# Django Sum & Count

Tags: django

I have some MySQL code that looks like this:

```
SELECT 
visitor AS team,
COUNT(*) AS rg,
SUM(vscore>hscore) AS rw,
SUM(vscore<hscore) AS rl 
FROM `gamelog` WHERE status='Final' 
      AND date(start_et) BETWEEN %s AND %s GROUP BY visitor
```

I'm trying to translate this into a Django version of that query, without making multiple queries. Is this possible? I read up on how to do `Sum()`, and `Count()`, but it doesn't seem to work when I want to compare two fields like I'm doing.

Here's the best I could come up with so far, but it didn't work...

```
vrecord = GameLog.objects.filter(start_et__range=[start,end],visitor=i['id']
                                 ).aggregate(
                                             Sum('vscore'>'hscore'),
                                             Count('vscore'>'hscore'))
```

I also tried using `'vscore>hscore'` in there, but that didn't work either. Any ideas? I need to use as few queries as possible.

Comment: Im guessing you have `vscore` and `hscore` as fields on your model? You'd have to do a `filter(vscore__gt=hscore)` and count and sum that, I beleive, but if you want to do less SQL queries i would use `.extra()` and supply the raw sql myself. It would be far more optimal.

Comment: Thanks limelights, I'm probably going to have to do it that way. I really don't want to use raw SQL, but I guess there's no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation only works on single fields in the Django ORM. I looked at the code for the various aggregation functions, and noticed that the single-field restriction is hardwired. Basically, when you use, say, `Sum(field)`, it just records that for later, then it passes it to the database-specific backend for conversion to SQL and execution. Apparently, aggregation and annotation are not standardized in SQL.

Anyway, you probably need to [use a raw SQL query.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: Thanks. I've been hoping to avoid raw SQL, so that the app would be usable in any DB. I suppose I'll have to go this route tho.

Comment: I think any solution that avoids raw SQL would need to be done as an update to Django.